# my xml failed when i tried to release my android application [cordova]

Tags: android, xml, cordova

when i try to build my application i have this error

this is the commande i'm doing

cordova build android --release

(node:20384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Parsing C:\Users\Melchior\Desktop\V1-Appli\cordova\platforms\andro
id\res\xml\config.xml failed)

Comment: Cordova CLI version? cordova-android version?

Comment: Even i am facing same issue. I am using cordova cli 8 and cordova android 7.1.0